# Python - Как записать CSV таблицу с разным количеством строк в столбцах?

Tags: python, json, csv

У меня есть база (json) вида:

```
article = {'выдача': [
    {
        {'организация':
            {'Название': 'Фирма1', 'Телефон': '79111111111', 'Сайт': 'site1.con'}},
        {'организация': 
            {'Название': 'Фирма2', 'Телефон': ['79111111121', '79111111122', '79111111123'], 'Сайт': ['site21.con', 'site22.con']}},
        {'организация': 
            {'Название': 'Фирма3', 'Телефон': ['79111111131', '79111111132'], 'Сайт': ['site31.con', 'site32.con', 'site33.con']}}}]}
```

У некоторых фирм есть по несколько телефонов или сайтов.

Мне нужно, чтобы в out.csv база записалась следующим образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вопрос:** Как записать CSV таблицу с разным количеством строк в столбцах?

Comment: То, что вы хотите получить на выходе - не является CSV. Прочитать этот файл обратно - большая и ненужная проблема... При желании можно использовать пустые строки на месте пробелов

Comment: @MaxU Спасибо! просто это удобно для ручной аналитики файла. Для обратного считывания использую JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подобный output можно получить из этих данных разными способами, давай попробуем через всеми любимую [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/) - pretty sure @MaxU is gonna "destroy" this solution :)

```
import pandas as pd


def expand_column(df, column_name):
    """Expands inner lists in columns."""
    series = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x[column_name]), axis=1).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
    series.name = column_name
    return df.drop(column_name, axis=1).join(series)


data = {'выдача': [
    {'организация':
         {'Название': 'Фирма1', 'Телефон': '79111111111', 'Сайт': 'site1.con'}},
    {'организация':
         {'Название': 'Фирма2', 'Телефон': ['79111111121', '79111111122', '79111111123'],
          'Сайт': ['site21.con', 'site22.con']}},
    {'организация':
         {'Название': 'Фирма3', 'Телефон': ['79111111131', '79111111132'],
          'Сайт': ['site31.con', 'site32.con', 'site33.con']}}
    ]
}

df = pd.DataFrame([item['организация'] for item in data['выдача']])

df = expand_column(df, 'Сайт')
df = expand_column(df, 'Телефон')

df.to_csv('output.csv')
```

Здесь мы использовали вот этот способ раскрытия значений внутри ячеек: [When cell contents are lists, create a row for each element in the list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27266225/771848).

В `output.csv` в итоге получилось вот что:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Большое спасибо!!